# GCP Connection error from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL postgre

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I setup my instances in GCP Cloud run, to connect to Cloud SQL DB (Postgres) but just one of this instances can establish connection with cloud SQL but the others can't, all instances uses the same host or internal IP, same user and password, also I create a new user and password but I can´t

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The answer below is a good one but you're not providing any details to this issue. Please add details to your questions since we cannot guess your configurations

Comment: Please read this link. Your question lacks details required to provide good/correct answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Are you having trouble connecting the cloud-run deployed instances to cloud SQL or connecting to cloud SQL in general? My first guess is that you have not whitelisted the public Ipv4 IP addresses for all locations that establish a direct TCP connection; however, if it is just an issue within the deployed CR instance, then I would check the following depending on how you are connecting:

1. Cloud SQL Auth Proxy
2. Private IP (IPv4 or IPv6 address accessible on a VPC)
3. Public IP (IPv4 or IPv6 address accessible to the public)

The easiest is to use public IP and ensure that all IAM roles and service accounts are available to the cloud run service account and alter the connection host to use Unix sockets instead of the original IP address using the proxy.

For example, in local development, your host may be something like 35.333.333.1, but when deployed into production, you need to change the host to use the Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the path "/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>".

The INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME can be found on the Overview page for your instance in the Google Cloud Console or by running the following command:

```
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME].
```

- Ensure that the service account used by cloud run (i.e., the service account seen on the security tab of the deploy new revision page, typically the default Compute Engine service account ending with '@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com') has the [proper roles and permissions needed to connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles). It will need at least one of the following

  - Cloud SQL Client (preferred)
  - Cloud SQL Editor
  - Cloud SQL Admin
    or manually assign the IAM permissions:
  - cloudsql.instances.connect
  - cloudsql.instances.get

This can all be taken care of for you using `gcloud` to deploy to cloud run like so (assuming the envvars/connection parameters are correct in your code):

If you are deploying a new container, use the following command:

```
gcloud run deploy --image IMAGE \
  --add-cloudsql-instances INSTANCE-CONNECTION-NAME \
  --update-env-vars INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME="INSTANCE-CONNECTION-NAME"
```

If you are updating an existing service, use the following command:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE-NAME \
  --add-cloudsql-instances INSTANCE-CONNECTION-NAME \
  --update-env-vars INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME="INSTANCE-CONNECTION-NAME"
```

See  here for details: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run

Comment: Following up with @ElsaPorico - without more context, this problem could get way too overcomplicated when the solution probably takes 5 seconds. Always nice to re-learn the complexities of GCP IAM, though.... not